# How to translate all the contents inside model queries in DJango?

Tags: django, django-i18n

i am a new to **Django**, i am trying to make a small blog with two different languages, i got all the translations inside my blog including the admin, but still don't know how to translate the content of my posts.

After i fetch the content using the **models queries**, inside my template i used to type this `{% trans "SOME TEXT" %}` and it works just fine, with variables that i am getting from database i am using this code:

```
{% blocktrans %}
    {{head.title_text}}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

now when i type `django-admin makemessages -l ru`, inside **django.po** i can't see any new text that have been added.

Also inside my **views.py** i tried this:

```
head = Head.objects.first()
trans_h = _(u'{}'.format(head))
```

but nothing gets added inside **django.po**

Please, anyone knows how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: it's not an issue, You can't translate content from the database

Comment: @Goran, Thanks for your interest. So is there any way to translate also the content?

Comment: Maybe i have to create two fields for each content so for example en_content and ru_content and depending on the activated language of the blog i will show them ??

Comment: yes, that 's the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to translate the content of the Post Model without using any third-party is to create for each fields you need to translate inside your models with different languages and translate them from your admin,and display them in your template when the site change the language, in Django you can translate only the text you can not translate the data from your model

Create your model Post

```html
models.py

class Post(models.Model)
    title_fr   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_en   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content_fr = models.TextField()
    content_en = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,   auto_now=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

In the view you translate the text inside the variable and pass it in your template

```html
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def post_view(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    
    # Here is you can translate the text in python 
    title = _("les meilleurs posts du mois")
    
    context = {
     'post':post,
     'title':title
    }
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Here the idea is once your site is translated in french for example([www.mysite.com/fr/](http://www.mysite.com/fr/)) in your template you will get only the attributes with _fr(title_fr, content_fr)  already translated in your admin and if it's in english it will be the same thing

```html
index.html


{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}

<h1> {{ title}}</h1>

{% if LANGUAGE_CODE|language_name_translated == 'Français' %}
{% for items in home %}
<h2>{{ items.title_fr }}</h2>
<p> {{items.content_fr}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% if LANGUAGE_CODE|language_name_translated == 'English' %}
{% for items in home %}
 <h2>{{ items.title_en }}</h2>
 <p>{{items.content_en}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I hope it can be helpful

Comment: Is it possible to pass these values to django rest framework?